# Python 2.7 Skimage IO NOT Working

Tags: python, image

I am trying to use skimage for image manipulation, however as soon as try to import io module the program abruptly ends.

```
from skimage import io

image = "asder10.jpg"
print("open image {}".format(image))
io.imread(image)
```

Output
I am not getting any output even the print is not working and it does not give any error.

> > > ================================ RESTART ================================

I appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are getting this output from IDLE? This is not output from your script at all. Just off the bat it looks like you don't quite know how to run IDLE properly. I use your code and get it to run (albeit with errors). From your script window, are you selecting "Run" >> "Run Module"?

Comment: Actually when I use a file in my path, your code works just fine. Assuming you have skimage properly installed your code should be fine.

Comment: Actually I use F5 to run module, which is similar to "Run" >> "Run Module". I am suspecting if there is problem with skimage installation but not sure. I know how to use IDLE, however never worked with skimage before.I use to work with PIL.

Comment: There was problem with the installation, I reinstalled skimage and now it is working fine. I guses skimage needs scipy which was missing in my system. However I am not sure how it get installed for the first time without any error/comments.

Comment: Yeah thats odd. Sci-kit image has a bunch of dependencies. Off the top of my head you need scipy, numpy, matplotlib, and cython. I would recommend using pip to make it all a little easier.

Comment: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html